# How to select by index

Tags: mysql

I want to reproduce this behavior:

```
sql = 'SELECT id FROM photos where index = 1' ---> I getting: 8
sql = 'SELECT id FROM photos where index = 2' ---> I getting: 9
sql = 'SELECT id FROM photos where index = -1' ---> I getting: 12

    +----+-----------+-------------------------------+
    | id | user_id   | photo
    +----+-----------+-------------------------------+
    |  1 | 1773      | s8uBdMI4AHBDgAEAQADAgADYwADCX0AAd 
    |  8 | 1773      | s8uBdMI4AHBDgAEAQADAgADYwADCX0AAh 
    |  9 | 1773      | w46YZqV89G6DwAEAQADAgADYwADWxgHAA 
    | 10 | 1773      | rVTM9pwXA8ABAEAAwIAA2MAA3MmAwABGg 
    | 11 | 1773      | KunArfCDwAEAQADAgADYwAD6CYBAAEaBA 
    | 12 | 1773      | fmupLIswQ4ABAEAAwIAA2MAA3RnAAIaBA 
    +----+-----------+-------------------------------+
```

DDL:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INTEGER,
photo VARCHAR(255), 
KEY (id),
KEY (photo),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, photo),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)""")
```

The problem is that sometimes (like here) `id` not preserve order. Possible solution - is to use `order by` every time, but maybe there any shorter way?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x? You can use `RANK()` in a window function to get the index.

Comment: How/Where did you define the field `index` ?

Comment: @Luuk He doesn't mean it as a column, it's the row number.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm using MySQL 8.x. Runk() working only in MySQL? Maybe there are function, that corresponding with ISO or another common database standard?

Comment: "Way back in 2003, the ANSI/ISO standards people figured this out and added windows and ranking functions to the standard."    (source: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/07/leaving-windows-open/ )  the article is about when Microsoft added it to MSSQL, but MySQL added this in version 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. You can specify index and rowcount in the `LIMIT` clause, so use `rowcount = 1` to get just one row at that index.

For negative indexes use descending order. Negate the index and subtract 1 because indexes start at `0`.

```
SELECT photo FROM photos
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1, 1; -- index 1

SELECT photo FROM photos
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 2, 1; -- index 2

SELECT photo FROM photos
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 1; -- index -1
```

Comment: In such a case maybe there a sense to add some key during table creation that will preserve order for no calculate `order by` every time?

Comment: @salius If `id` is the primary key, it preserves order.

Comment: If you add an `index` column to the table, you'll need to update it every time you delete rows.

Comment: added DDL to a question, so `id` has a `AUTO INCREMENT` and `KEY`, but not a `PRIMARY KEY`